# How to understand dereferences and generic pointer in order to see the output?

Tags: c

Why is the output: `aa b ee f ii j`? Did the line: `void (*pFunc)(void*);` create a function `pFunc` that is similar to function `print`? I know that a void pointer is a generic pointer but still, how did the output come to be the way it is?
The arguments at the command line: `aaa eee iii`

```
void print (void *a)
{
   char**p=(char**)a;

   printf("%s",(*p+1));
   putchar('');
   putchar(**p+1);
   putchar('');

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int i;
   void(*pFunc)(void*);
   pFunc=print;
   for(i=1; i< argc;i++)
      pFunc(argv+i);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking what does print do? How does this function pointer work? Or maybe, why converting to and from `void *` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did the row: `void (*pFunc)(void*);` creates a function `pFunc` that is similar to function print?

Yes. `void (*pFunc)(void*);` declare `pFunc` as a pointer to a function that return type is `void` and expects an argument of type `void *`.

> Why is the output: `aa b ee f ii j`?

The snippet

```
for(i=1; i< argc;i++) 
      pFunc(argv+i);
```

passes all of you strings `aaa`, `eee` and `iii` to the function `print`. There you are casting `a` to `char **`.
For first string `aaa`, `*p` is pointer to its first `char` and `*p+1` to second `char.`   Statement

```
printf("%s",(*p+1));
```

will print the string from second character, i.e it will print `aa`.
`**P` is a `char` and `**p+1` increment the ascii value of that character and `putchar(**p+1);` will print that character.  ASCII value of `a` is `97` and `98` `b`.

Therefore, the output for `aaa` is `aa b`. Same goes for other arguments.

Answer (score 1):

What else would you expect?

This:

```
*p+1
```

means: "Dereference `p`, and add `1` to the resulting value."
Since `p` dereferenced is a `char*`, you get an offset of 1 character, resulting in "aaa" becoming "aa", and likewise for "e" and "i".

And this:

```
**p+1
```

means: "Dereference `p`, then dereference the resulting value, then add `1`."
Since the result of dereferencing a `char**` twice is the first character of the first string of that array, the "resulting value" is `97`, or `'a'`, interpreted as a character.
Add `1` to that and you get `98`, or `'b'`, interpreted as a character.
The same goes for "e" and "i" again.

Also:

> Did the line: `void (*pFunc)(void*);` create a function pFunc that is similar to function `print`?

No. You just made `pFunc` another name for `print`.
The functionality is therefore not similar, but identical.

Answer (score 0):

*p has higher precedence than +1 so this is what is happening:

you're sending three argments:

```
->aaa
->eee
->iii
```

*p+1 points at the first character plus one, so it points at the second character. So, you print `aa` instead of `aaa`
**p+1 returns that value of the first character and adds one to it, giving you `b`.

Each of the commands operates the same, moving one into the string the first printf and incrementing the character by one in the interesting putchar command.